# How do find next occurrence of a string after a string position?

Tags: php, string

I find an occurrence of a string, let's say Chocolate, in a string, and I'm trying to find if chocolate is part of anchor text inside a link.  The easiest way I considered doing this is finding the next < character to see if it is followed by /a>

I don't know how to find the next occurrence of a string from a string position number.  Is there a function that does this easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third parameter of [`strpos`](http://us.php.net/strpos) is a starting offset.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't consider offset.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does php strpos not serve your purpose ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

It has an offset parameter , to find next occurence of string from that number